# With Retrofit2, unable to send JSON body in POST request

Tags: java, android, post, retrofit, retrofit2

I am using the following piece of code to implement an API with the POST method and raw `JsonObject` as body.

```java
public interface PostRawJsonService {
    @POST
    Call<Model> submitData(@Url String url, @HeaderMap Map<String, String> headers, @Body Email email);
}
```

The email model is:

```
public class Email {
    private String email;

    public Email(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }
}
```

And I am calling it like this:

```java
Email email= new Email("team@gmail.com");
Call<Model> call = service.submitData(url, headers, email);
```

This isn't working and code seems to be stuck at `Call<Model> call = service.submitData(url, headers, email);` line , and the log isn't showing any error as well. What could be the issue?

While I'm printing the request, it is as follows:

```
{   "body": {
    "contentType": {
      "mediaType": "application/json",
      "subtype": "json",
      "type": "application"
    }   },   "headers": {
    "namesAndValues": [
      "Authorization",
      "xyz"
    ]   },   "method": "POST",   "url": {
    "host": "my.company.com",
    "password": "",
    "pathSegments": [
      "data",
      "next",
      "email"
    ],
    "port": 443,
    "scheme": "https",
    "url": "https://my.company.com/data/next/email",
    "username": ""   } }
```

Comment: you using retrofit 2?

Comment: yes, i am using retrofit2

Answer (score 0):

Create getter and setter methods inside an Email class:

```
public class Email {
    private String email;

    public Email(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getEmail(){
      return this.email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email){
      this.email = email;
    }
}
```

Comment: Same issue with this.

Answer (score 0):

```
HashMap<String, String> headerMap = new HashMap<>();
headerMap.put("SessionID", "Session");
headerMap.put("UserName", "Username");
headerMap.put("Content-Type", "application/json");

OkHttpClient httpClient = // Create OkHttpClient
```

I used this method to get httpclient:

```
public OkHttpClient addHeaders(final HashMap<String, String> headerMap) {
    return new OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .addInterceptor(new Interceptor() {
                @Override
                public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
                    Request.Builder builder = chain.request().newBuilder();
                    Set<String> keySets = headerMap.keySet();
                    for (String key : keySets) {
                        builder.addHeader(key, headerMap.get(key));
                    }
                    return chain.proceed(builder.build());
                }
            })
            .readTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .connectTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .build();
}

PostRawJsonService service = ConnectToService
        .newInstance()
        .getClient(httpClient).create(PostRawJsonService.class);
```

Here ConnectToService is my common class used to create retrofit. You use it in your own class which you are using now.

And service by placing body to front and url to next:

```
Call<Model> call = service.submitData(email, url);
```

Comment: Adding headers has no issue, Body of POST request is causing the problem.

Comment: 1) try by placing url at first and body at second in that submitData method and check.
If that not working kindly check 2nd option
2) try without body and check whether u can able to call the service and able to receiving at service end

Comment: Can you make sure that you are hitting complete url ?

Comment: @Faraz. Check in the posted request url is complete

Comment: I mean to say the root url + extended url are complete ?

Comment: and sending @Body Map<String, String> body instead of class object worked for me.